# I want to convert uppercase words to lowercase in dataframe and put them below

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1. convert uppercase to lowercase
2. add below it.

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| Acceptive | Acceptive koean mean |
| Access | Access koean mean |

=>

| en | ko |
| --- | --- |
| Acceptive | Acceptive koean |
| acceptive | Acctptive koean |
| Access | Access koean |
| access | Accesskoean |

please help !!!!!!!

Comment: Do you want to convert capitals to small letters only on 'en' columns? Then, how about 'ko' columns?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
I just want to change only English to lowercase and then bring Korean as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the input is like this form.

```
>>> df
      en  ko
0  Apple  사과
1    Ant  개미
```

First, repeat the rows.

```
>>> df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)].reset_index(drop = True)
>>> df2
      en  ko
0  Apple  사과
1  Apple  사과
2    Ant  개미
3    Ant  개미
```

Now, you can lower the odd rows.

```
>>> for row in range(len(df)):
...     df2.loc[2*row+1].en = df2.loc[2*row+1].en.lower()

>>> df2
      en  ko
0  Apple  사과
1  apple  사과
2    Ant  개미
3    ant  개미
```

Comment: Is it df or df2 in the third part?

Comment: @이승우, Sorry I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

First, we convert each element of the `en` column into a list containing the same text in original and lower case. Then we use `explode()` to "unpack" the values of the list into different strings

```
df.en = df.en.apply(lambda x: [x,x.lower()])
df = df.explode('en',ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

The same in one line:

```
df = df.assign(en=lambda y: y.en.apply(lambda x: [x, x.lower()])).explode('en',ignore_index=True)
```

```
          en                    ko
0  Acceptive  Acceptive koean mean
1  acceptive  Acceptive koean mean
2     Access     Access koean mean
3     access     Access koean mean
```